# mySQL select price records that have changed by X% over time

Tags: mysql

If I have a table of dates, prices, product_ids, I'd like to return all product_IDs where the current price has dropped X% over Y days.

So for example, find all products that have dropped in price by 10% or more over past 4 weeks, or 20% or more over past 8 weeks.

How can I query for that?

Sample table Data

| Sell_Date | Product_ID | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 | 0001 | 50.00 |
| 2021-01-03 | 0001 | 45.00 |
| 2021-03-02 | 0001 | 37.00 |
| 2021-01-04 | 0002 | 75.00 |
| 2021-02-04 | 0002 | 65.00 |

How could I return rows 2, 3 and 5 from above for showing which products had prices that had lowered by at least 10% over the past month or, row 3 if I queried for 20% price reductions over past 2 months?

Comment: What did you try yourself? (and why did that fail?)

Comment: Im not sure if I need to use like a row over window function.  Im not sure how to compare a price today, to any prices in the past, I don't know how to make that reference.  Or maybe I can use a subquery, select the max value and group by product ID, and then see if price is less than X% of the max value, something like that.  Im just not sure how to constsuct the query.

Comment: And note that your sample data set is not particularly helpful as it would return all rows except the first in each group.

Comment: Ok, should I delete this question and submit again with better example data and a more clear explanation?